# How to invoke callback at end of DoubleAnimation inside of a longer Storyboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a Storyboard that contains multiple DoubleAnimations.  I would like to execute a function whenever one of the children completes.  However, If I attach an EventHandler to the `Completed` event of one of the DoubleAnimations, it does not get invoked until the entire Storyboard has finished.

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, 500, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)));
    anim1.Completed += anim1_Complete;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, circle);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
    myStoryboard.Children.Add(anim1);

    DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(500, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,2)));
    anim2.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,2);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(anim2, circle);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
    myStoryboard.Children.Add(anim2);
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}

void anim1_Complete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("anim 1 complete");
}
```

How can I get notified when one of the child Animations completes?

I realize that in this minimalist example I've provided it would be easy to create two storyboards (or Animations) and have the Complete event of the first trigger the start of the second.  However, that's not the kind of answer I'm looking for. 
I want to be able to maintain one master timeline that I can pause, resume, seek, reverse, etc. and get notified whenever a sub-timeline's beginning or end is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that circle is a UIElement try this:

```
DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, 500, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)));
anim1.Completed += anim1_Complete;

circle.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, anim1);
```

Same for the other animation.
So no StoryBoard.

Comment: Yes, _technically_ that's not using two storyboards, but it amounts to the same thing.  
Please see the bit at the end of the question that says, "I want to be able to maintain one master timeline that I can pause, resume, seek, reverse, etc. and get notified whenever a sub-timeline's beginning or end is passed."